# Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER= 'sports'`@`'%'` PROCEDURE `CheckMembership`(IN BrandId int,
 IN Email varchar(128),
 IN PhoneNumber varchar(10),
 OUT ResponseCode int,
 OUT ResponseMessage varchar(256))
BEGIN
declare _count int;

select count(*) from Member where Phone1 = PhoneNumber into _count;

set ResponseCode = 1;
set ResponseMessage = '';

END
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this stored procedure as I a new to this and couldnot find any good solution in the internet . All I need to do is to get the count value by running it in php

Comment: why are you using a stored procedure if all you want to do is get the count in php?

Comment: this is what the client wants

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the syntax of the `SELECT` statement is wrong because the `INTO` clause is misplaced.

That should follow the `SELECT` list and come before the `FROM` keyword. For example:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO _count 
  FROM Member 
 WHERE Phone1 = PhoneNumber ;
```

Syntax help is available in MySQL Reference Manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html

---

I'm not sure if this answers the question you were asking. (It's not at all clear *what* question you *were* asking.)

---

**Q:** I don't know how to call this stored procedure in a php file to get the answers.

From PHP, I think you would need to use MySQL user-defined variables for the OUT arguments, and retrieve those values with a separate `SELECT` statement:

As a simple demonstration of a pattern you could use, given the arguments of the procedure as shown in the question:

```sql
-- set user defined variables
SELECT @brandid = 'fee', @email = 'fi', @phonenumber = 'fo', @rc := '', @rm := '';

-- execute stored procedure with user-defined variables as arguments
CALL CheckMembership(@brandid, @email, @phonenumber, @rc, @rm);

-- retrieve user-defined variables
SELECT @rc AS ResponseCode, @rm AS ResponseMessage;
```

To return the "count" value, you could follow the same pattern. Modify the procedure to add another `OUT` parameter, and then set that to the value of that parameter in the procedure.

(This seems an unnecessary rigmarole, using a stored procedure to return a result which could just as easily be returned by a simple query.)

Comment: I don't know how to call this stored procedure in a php file to get the answers

Comment: @SnigdhodebMitra I would start with the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php